# Y86 error "invalid line" for jump instruction

Tags: y86

I am writing a program in y86, but I am getting some strange errors. It is saying for the third line "invalid line."

```
    irmovl  0, %eax        #clear eax
    andl    %edi, %edi
    jg  .L9              
    jmp .L7
```

These types of errors come at all of the jump type instructions throughout my code

Answer (score 0):

Well, did you define .L7 and .L9?  If not, small wonder...

This works, but it is rather meaningless, of course (and you should probably avoid using periods in labels):

```
irmovl  0, %eax        #clear eax
andl    %edi, %edi
jg  .L9              
jmp .L7

.align 4
.L9: 0
.L7: 0

halt
```